# Printing on screen array elements with Delay/Repeating them by using a callback function Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, settimeout, delay

I'm trying to print the given array cells with 2 seconds delay for each element between every print 
by using a **callback** function but i cant make it work. 
Instead it prints them all together after 2 seconds

here is the code:

```
var words = ["horse","pig","fish","lion"]
var time

function display(callback){
    time = setTimeout(typing, 2000);
}

function typing(){
    for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++)
        document.write(words[i])
}
display(typing);
```

I could also use some help with this code too if possible. If the first variable(a in this case) is a number and the second variable(b in this case) is a String it should print the string as many times as the number of variable a.
This one does not work at all :/

here is the code:

```
function display(callback) {
   time = setTimeout(typing, 1000)
}
function typing(a,b) {
   var aInput = prompt("Please enter a input");
   aInput = a
   var bInput = prompt("Please enter b input");
   bInput = b
     if (a === int)
       for (i=0; i<a.length; i++)
          alert(b)
   else 
      alert("Not valid Input")
    }

display(typing);
```

thanks a lot in advance for the huge help this community gives to starters :)

Comment: _setTimeout(typing, 2000)_  implies that `typing` is run 2 seconds after `setTimeout` is called. Hence, the elements are printed together after 2 seconds. You have to call the `seTimeout` function within the loop in order to print array elements every 2 seconds. Is using a callback function mandatory? What should this callback function contain?

Comment: the callback isnt even being used. you can use that or...take it out?

Comment: unfortunately callback must be used. It doesn't have to contain something specific. I started coding two months ago I know some things may not be perfect and I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question. All the words are printed after 2 seconds because for loop doesn't wait with each cycle till the execution of `setTimeout` is finished, therefore it runs all the `setTimeout`s almost instantly and the each of them waits for 2 seconds, apparently finishing at the same time. You can change it like this.

```js
var words = ["horse","pig","fish","lion"]

function display() {
  let counter = 0;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    document.write(words[counter++]);
    if (counter === words.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 2000);
}

display();
```

As for the second problem. That can be solved in a similar fashion.

```js
function display(a, b) {

  // if a and b were passed to the function use those
  // otherwise ask for them by prompting the user
  let aInput = a || prompt('Please enter a input');
  let bInput = b || prompt('Please enter b input');

  // check if a is valid integer (could also use Math.floor if floats are valid in your case as well)
  if (!isNaN(parseInt(a))) {
    let counter = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      alert(b);
      counter++;
      if (counter >= parseInt(a)) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    alert('Not a valid input');
  }
}

display(4, 'a');
```

Comment: there has to be a callback function involved but thanks

Comment: @ChrisA. There is a callback, although an anonymous one.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with the second code:

1. You are taking input through `prompt` so you don't need to pass any argument to `typing`.
2. For the above reason, a and b are undefined. So, `aInput = a` and `bInput = b` make no sense. Instead, store the values of aInput  and bInput in a and b respectively.
3. `if (a === int)` is wrong syntax. There is no such thing as int in JavaScript. If you wan to check if a is a number use `isNaN(a)`.
4. The `for loop` within the `if-statement` must be wrapped in {} since it has more than one lines.

This should work fine:

```
function display(callback) {
   time = setTimeout(typing, 1000)
}

function typing() {
   var aInput = prompt("Please enter a input");
   var a = Number(aInput); 
   var bInput = prompt("Please enter b input");
   var b = bInput;
     if (!isNaN(a)){
       for (var i=0; i<a; i++){
          alert(b);
        }
    }
   else {
      alert("Not valid Input")
    }
}

display(typing);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of things, you should be doing this part:

```
var aInput = prompt("Please enter a input");
aInput = a
var bInput = prompt("Please enter b input");
bInput = b
```

before:

```
time = setTimeout(typing, 1000)
```

and then sending in your a and b parameters to:

```
typing(a,b)
```

If you do it that way, it should work.

Comment: I assume this is some sort of homework assignment? The next part would probably be fore you to get the callback working properly.